# Why is Shiva primarily worshipped in a linga form?

Tags: shiva, worship, temple, shiva-lingam

In Hindu temples, the statues of the deities are present in the sanctum. But in (most) Shiva temples, only a linga is present instead of a Shiva statue. The linga worship seems to be limited only to Shiva, since no other deity is worshipped widely in linga form.

Why is Shiva primarily (and uniquely) worshipped in the linga form?

Comment: IMHO linga is representative of the totality of God, that is, the fullness of God and His completeness, all of which are aspects of the linga. I'm just speculating here: Ishvarah refers to this complete God or Supreme Being, since Ishvara has become synonymous with Lord Shiva in recent times, these forms of linga have become associated with Lord Shiva, and obviously sectarian beliefs would prevent other devotees to depict their form of God in the same way.

Comment: Shiva was preached as destroyer only. Shivites depicted him in form of Penis(Linga) with thought that he is creator too.  Shiva creates, Shiva Destroyes

Comment: Shivalinga is the form of God in its totality, the only, what Hindus call paramasivam, male and female energy in constant orgasm, it is an expression, shivalinga and Shiva are different.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 35):

I am giving an additional account. The linga form of worship is the symbolic worship of Lord Shiva. As per Puranas like Brahmanda purana, Linga Purana, in the very beginning Shiva appeared to Brahma and Vishnu in the form of a bright splendor column of light whose beginning and end  they both could not find out. **So the *linga* form of Shiva also signifies the column of bright light.** This account was narrated by the sage Sūta when other sages asked him about the origin of the linga:

> *kathaṃ liṃgamabhūlliṃge samabhyarcyaḥ sa śaṃkaraḥ
>
>      kiṃ liṃgaṃ kastathā liṃgī sūta vaktumihārhasi* [LP - 17.2]
>
> **Meaning**
>   How can there be *linga* of God who is *alingi* (without *linga*). How the *linga* of Shankara is worshipped? What is *linga* and what is *lingi*? O Suta, please tell us these.

Then Sūta goes on to narrate how Brhama had earlier given answers to the same questions to the gods. The linga form of Siva had appeared before the beginning of creation at the time when Vishnu and Brahma were engaged in arguments:

> *etasminnantare liṃgamabhavaccāvayoḥ puraḥ
>
>   vivādaśamanārthaṃ hi prabodhārthaṃ ca bhāsvaram
>
>   jvālāmālāsahasrāḍhyaṃ kālānalaśatopamam
>
>   kṣayavṛddhivinirmuktamādimadhyāṃtavarjitam*  [LP - 17.33,34]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Then after that a bright *linga* appeared between both of us to counsel our arguments. That linga was surrounded by thousands of flames and hot like fire of death. Without any beginning and end, that was free from decay and growth.

So apart from the commonly known reason of the *linga* worship, this is another account we find in our scriptures.

Comment: When there was no beginning and end then how can you say it was in Linga Form? It could be a cyclone, Road, Try anything but not linga

Comment: nice answer SADASHIVA is worshipped as eternal light (illuminious Jyotirllinga), believed by the meditation specialists Brahmakumaris as well.

Answer (score 25):

First of all the real name is not Shiva Linga, The real name is Jyotirlingam.

It is a form of Jyoti. Jyoti is a fire, whose shape is exactly the shape of lingam.

### Question is why lingam for only shiva?

"Shiva appeared in jyotirlingam form to solve dispute of Brahma and Vishnu" so for shiva, jyotirlingam is not full truth.

We need to put focus more on Shiva's actual form to understand this answer, which is "Nirguna" according to Rigveda and Shiva maha purana.

Shiva gave his introduction to Vishnu and Brahma

> Gyan Swaroopam Shivohm Shivohm (Brahma)
>   Neejanand swaroopam Shivohm Shivohm (Vishnu)
>   Prakash Swaroopam Shivohm Shivohm (Mahesh- Shiva's 3rd eye)

On hearing this both Brahma and Vishnu prayed to Shiva to appear so that they can see him. Shiva appeared in Jyotirlingam form, this jyoti was a fire of love.

The 12 Jyotirlingam are 12 Jyotirstambha of Shiva. Shiva is the only deity who is accepted as "Neerakar Nerguna Brahm".

The origin of word "Aadi" came into existence because for anything's existence we have time based exam. Nobody knows the origin of time because nobody exactly existed to check Shiva's origin.

So, when Vishnu came to know about Shiva's introduction Vishnu explained that Shiva is actually a seed, Shiva is a seed and whatever we see is a tree originated from that seed -> That is "Lingam".

From The Mahabharata, Anusasana Parva -> Veda Vyasa Mahabharata

> The blessed Vishnu said: "I salute Mahadeva. Salutations to Thee. O Thou that art eternal origin of all things. The Rishis say that Thou art the Lord of the Vedas. The righteous say that Thou art Penance, Thou art Sattwa, Thou art Rajas, Thou art Tamas, and Thou art truth.

Vishnu himself said "Shiva is eternal origin of ..." That's why Shiva linga is seed and Whatever we see it is just a tree from that seed.

It is origin. Shiva is originator so Shiva is worshiped in the form of Jyotirlinam.

Comment: Nice answer. Can you post a link to that quote from Anusasana Parva?

Answer (score 22):

This question can be answered into two aspects:

> 1) Why is Linga form worshipped ?
>   2) Why is Shiva primarily worshipped in Linga form ?

### 1) Why is Linga form worshipped ?

Among the 18 major Mahapuranas one of the Purana is named **Linga Purana**, thus glorifying the status of Linga.

Linga is worshipped because Linga contains everything of this world. In the Linga Purana [part 2 chapter 46], once sages have debate regarding why Linga form is worshipped. Then Goddess Saraswati comes there and states this fact:

> अथांतरिक्षे विपुला साक्षाद्देवी सरस्वती ।
>   अलं मुनीनां प्रश्नोऽयमिति वाचा बभूव ह ।।
>   **सर्वं लिंगमयं लोकं सर्वं लिंगे प्रतिष्ठितम् ।**
>   तस्मात्सर्वं परित्यज्य स्थापयेत्पूजयेच्च तत् ।।
>  
>   May the questions of the sages stop. **The whole world is identical with the Linga. Everything is found on the Linga.** Hence, one shall eschew everything, install the Linga and worship it.

Goddess Saraswati also states all Gods are situated in a Linga. She states:

> स्वेषुस्वेषु च पक्षेषु प्रदानास्ते यथा द्विजाः |
>   ब्रह्मा हरश्च भगवान्विष्णुर्देवी रमा धरा ।। 
>   लक्ष्मीर्धृति: स्मृति: प्रज्ञा धरा दुर्गा शची तथा ।
>   रुद्राश्च वसव: स्कन्दो विशाख: शाख यव च ।।
>   नैगमेशश्च भगवाँल्लोकपाला ग्रहास्तथा ।
>   सर्वे नंदिपुरोगाश्च गणा गणपति: प्रभु: ।।
>   पितरो मुनय: सर्वे कुबेराद्याश्च सुप्रभा: ।
>   आदित्या वसव: सांख्या अश्चिनौ च भिषग्वरौ ।।
>   विश्वेदेवाश्व साध्याश्च पशव: पक्षिणों मृगा:। 
>   ब्रह्मादिस्थावरांतं च सर्वं लिंगे प्रतिष्ठितम् ।।
>   तस्मात्सर्वं परित्यज्य स्थापयेल्लिंगमव्ययम् ।
>   यत्नेन स्थापितं सर्वं पूजितं पूजयेद्यदि ।।
>  
>   All the deities like Brahma, śiva, Earth, Lakshmi, dhṛti, smṛti, prajñā, durgā, śacī, Rudra, Vasu, Skanda, viśākha, śākha, naigameśa, dikapalakās(guardians of the directions), the planets, gaṇās, nandī, Ganapati, pitṛ gaṇās, ṛṣis , kubera, āditya, sāṃkhya, aśvinīkumārās- the best of the physicians, viśvadevās, sādhyās , paśus, birds and animals, besides all the mobile and immobiles, starting from Brahma are established in the linga. Therefore, leaving aside everything, linga should be consecrated. After consecrating it  with all the efforts, incase, one adores the shivalinga, then he gets adorable by all.

Thus as every Gods are situated in Linga it is highly auspicious to worship Linga. Trinities are situated in Linga and it is also stated in the next chapter ie. [Part 2 chapter 47] of Linga Purana:

> मूले ब्रह्मा वसति भगवान्मध्यभागे च विष्णु: ।
>   सर्वेशानः पशुपतिरजो रुद्रमूर्तिर्वरेण्यः ।।
>  
>   Lord Brahma resides at the root, Lord Vishnu in the middle. The lord of all unborn Pasupati in the form of Rudra resides at the top.

Thus as Godesses Saraswati herself state "Sarva Linge Pratisthitam" ie. "Everything is situated in Linga". So, worship of Linga is highly auspicious and hence Linga form is worshipped.

### 2) Why is Shiva primarily worshipped in Linga form ?

Now, here comes this question. Other Gods and Godesses are worshipped in idol form whereas why Shiva is worshipped primarily in Linga form?

**It is related with the inseparable relation of Shiva and Shakti and linga form represents it.** The relationship of Uma and Maheswara is like that of word and meaning. It is illustrated in Vayaviya samhita Shiva Purana, Shiva-Shakti Vibhuti chapter:

> शब्दजालमशेषं तु धत्ते सर्वस्य वल्लभा ।
>   अर्थस्वरुपमखिलं धत्ते मुग्धेन्दुशेखरः ।।
>  
>   The beloved  of Shiva **(Uma) is in the form of words.** The moon crested Lord **(Maheswara) is in the form of meaning of those words.**

So, just as meaning is formless and it gets manifested through words. In the similar way formless Shiva gets manifested through Shakti. The same chapter also states:

> एवं परस्परापेक्षा शक्तिशक्तिमतोः स्थिता ।
>   न शिवेन विना शक्तिर्न शक्त्या च विना शिवः ।।
>  
>   There is mutual dependence between Shakti and Shaktiman. **There is no Shakti without Shiva and no Shiva without Shakti.**

The inseparable relationship of Shiva and Shakti is also shown by image or idol form of ArdhaNarishwara form. However Linga form is the only form which establishes word-meaning relationship. It is because **formless Shiva gets manifested in Linga form through the base of Shakti.** It is shown in Linga Purana [part 2 chapter 47]:

> विशोध्य स्थापत्येद्भक्त्या सवेदिकमनुत्तमम् ।
>   **लिंगवेदी उमा देवी लिंगं साक्षान् महेश्वर** ।।
>  
>   The Devotee shall clean Linga along with the pedestal and then devoutly install it. The **pedestal of the Linga is Godess Uma** and **the Linga is Maheswara himself.**

Thus as pedestal of Linga is Uma/ Shakti herself, thus it establishes inseparable Shiva-Shakti relationship. It shows that Nirguna Shiva gets manifested as the base of Shakti. So as it represents the Nirguna aspect, Shiva Purana [Videysavara samhita chapter 5] states:

> रुपित्वात्सकलस्तद्वत्तस्मात्सकलनिष्कल ।
>   निष्कलत्त्वान्निराकारं लिंगं तस्य समागतम् ।।
>  
>   He is also Sakala as he has an embodied form. He is both Sakala and Niskala (formless/Nirguna). **It is in his Niskala aspect that the Linga is appropriate as it represents formless aspect.**

And it also denotes the infiniteness of Linga as stated by Vyasa in Drona Parva [Chapter 202] of Mahabharata:

> दहत्यूर्ध्वं स्थितो यच्म प्राणेत्पतिस्थितश्चयत् ।
>   **स्थितलिङ्गस्य पन्नित्यं** तस्मात्स्थाणुरिति स्मृतः ।।
>  
>   Since he is great and ancient and is the source of the life and it's continuence and since **his Linga form is everlasting,** he is for that reason called Sthanu.

So, Lord Shiva is primarily worshipped in Linga form because it is the only form which establishes inseparable relationship of Shiva-Shakti, it represents manifestation of Nirguna in Saguna form and Linga is identical with the Universe itself and it  represents infinity too. Thus it is best to worship Lord Shiva in Linga form.

### Misconceptions:

Here are also answers which state Lord Shiva is primarily worshipped in Linga form due to curse of Sage Bhrigu. It is wrong because Lord Shiva is worshipped in Linga form from time beginning.

**Curse of Bhrigu took place in recent Kaliyuga while Lord Shiva is worshipped in Linga form much much before that.**

For eg. Rama worshipped Lord Shiva in Linga form. It is stated in Padma Purana [Patala Khanda chapter 104] and Lord Rama himself states it as:

> विभिषणः कथमसौबद्धः श्रृंखलयानृभि: ।
>   मत्स्थापितंशिवलिङ्गंदृष्ट्वारामेश्वरंत्वहो ।।
>  
>   Oh, how is it that Vibhisana seeing **the Linga of Shiva, (called) Ramesvara and installed by me,** is bound with chains.

And most importantly, curse of Bhrigu took place in this Kaliyuga, whereas there is a Mahapurana named Linga Purana which is among 18 Mahapuranas which is fully related with worship, origin, importance of Lingas and it is not that Vyasa wrote this Purana after curse by Bhrigu.

So, it is not due to curse of Bhrigu. Lord Shiva is always worshipped primarily in Linga form from time beginning.

The establishment of 12 Jyotirlinga:

> Somanath Jyotirlinga, Mallikarjuna Jyotirlinga, Mahakala Jyotirlinga, Omkareshwara Jyotirlinga, Kedareshwara Jyotirlinga, Bhimashankara Jyotirlinga, Visveswara Jyotirlinga, Trayambakeshwara Jyotirlinga, Vaidyanath Jyotirlinga, Nageswara Jyotirlinga, Rameshwara Jyotirlinga, Ghusmeshwara Jyotirlinga

All Jyotirlingas were established in Linga form from the time of their establishment. **They took much and much before curse of Bhrigu.** Some took place even before birth of Parvati. *For eg. Moon God established Somanath Linga during the time of Daksha Prajapati when he curses Moon God. Similarly Vaidyanath Jyotirlinga is related during the period of Ravana. And similarly all Jyotirlinga were established already before curse of Bhrigu.*

Moreover Skanda Purana describes more than 108 Shiva lingas which were already established before curse of Bhrigu. Shiva Purana also states about Lingas like:

> Rudresvara linga, Bhuteshwara linga, Bhimeshwara linga, Guptesvara linga, Vatukeswara linga, Kumareswara linga, Kameswara linga, Nadiswara linga, etc.. etc... so much

And these all were established in Linga form the beginning ie. Lord Shiva manifested himself as Linga form in those places. It is not that someone changed the image/idol from there and established Linga after curse of Bhrigu.

Thus it clearly shows that Lord Shiva was worshipped in Linga form from time beginning and it is not due to curse of Bhrigu. 

**Mahabharat also clearly states Lord Shiva to be worshipped in Linga form** (and it is also before curse of Bhrigu). Lord Krishna in Anushasana Parva Dana Dharma section and Vyasa in Drona Parva[chapter 202] state the same thing:

> ऋषयश्चैव देवाश्च गन्धर्वात्सरसस्तथा ।
>   लिङ्गमस्यार्चयन्ति स्म तच्मात्यूर्ध्वं समास्थितम् ।।
>  
>   **The Rishis, the Gods,** the Gandharvas and Apsaras, **always worship the Linga form** which is supposed to stand upright.

Thus from the above facts it is ridiculous to say that Linga worship started after curse of Bhrigu. Curse of Bhrigu may have created only some coincidental circumstances. That's it only. Lord Shiva is worshipped in Linga form from time beginning.

### Finally,

Worshipping of Linga is highly auspicious as it contains all Gods and Goddesses, as it is identical with the Universe itself, as it represents the Nirguna Brahman, as it represents inseparable relation of Shiva-Shakti.

Lord Krishna in Anushashana Parva Dana Dharma section and Vyasa in *Drona Parva [Chapter 202]* states;

> पूजयेद्विग्रहं यस्तु लिङ्ग वापि समर्चयेत् ।
>   लिङ्ग पूजयिता नित्यं महतीं श्रियमश्रुत ।।
>  
>   **He who adoreth Linga form of that high souled God, always obtained prosperity by that act.**

**And worship of Shiva Linga is in accordance with the Shruti/ Vedas. Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda in 10.16.2 states:**

> भवाय नमः । भवलिङ्गाय नमः ।।
>   शर्वाय नमः । शर्वलिङ्गाय नमः ।।
>   **शिवाय नमः । शिवलिङ्गाय नमः** ।।
>   ज्वलाय नमः । ज्वललिङ्गाय नमः ।।
>  
>   Salutation to Bhava and Salutations to Linga of Bhava. Salutations to Sarva and Salutations to Linga of Sarva. **Salutations to Shiva and Salutations to Linga of Shiva.** Salutations to your form of fire and Salutations to the Linga of fire.

Comment: it is phallus or not ?

Comment: @Ajay Well, after some days I'm going to answer a question related to this... wait for it...  I'll try to clear all misconceptions about Linga there...

Comment: @Ajay you should not follow Hinduism to defend.. following Hinduism is for self-realisation. It's for knowing the inner Purusha. It's for knowing the Brahaman. Who doesn't believe comes with his self imaginary loop holes. Anyway I'm not interested in convincing anyone for anything. I just write so that true seeker gets some benefits by reading my answer. I just said true seeker. And I again said true seeker. Again I told true seeker. True seeker. Jijnasa (true curiosity). Athato Brahman jijnasa.. athato Dharma jijnasa... athato Yoganusandhanam... curiosity.. curiosity... curiosity to know...

Comment: So,  what does a Shiva linga represent?

Comment: @Ajay Source of seed is called as Linga.

Comment: That curse incident you're talking about.. but rishi bhrigu is ancient rishi, right? I mean not from Kaliyuga

Answer (score 13):

[This excerpt](http://gdurl.com/aM7k) from the Uttara Kanda of the Padma Purana recounts the story of how Shiva worship came to be restricted to the linga.  A group of sages were once conducting a yagna (ritual) on the banks of the Saraswati river, when they started to wonder which god to dedicate the ritual to.  So they sent sage [Bhrigu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhrigu) (famous for his short temper) to test which god out of Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva was most worthy.  When he went to [Mount Kailash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Kailash) to test Shiva, [Nandi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nandi_%28bull%29) (Shiva's bull) prevented Bhrigu from meeting Shiva, because Shiva and Parvati were engaged in amorous pursuits at the time.  Enraged by this disrespect, Bhrigu put a curse on Shiva that from then onwards he could only be worshipped in the form of a linga.  (By the way, if you're interested Vishnu was the one who ultimately won the test, although it had major ramifications that led to [the story of Tirupati Balaji, AKA Venkateshwara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara#Legend).)

EDIT: Dharmaputhiran points out that the Wikipedia article about Venkateshwara I linked to claims that according to the Tirumala Sthala Purana (the temple scripture of the Tirupati temple), Shiva was actually engaged in deep meditation when Brighu visited him.  But Wikipedia is wrong about this; [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/O1KD) from the Tirumala Sthala Purana shows that Shiva and Parvati were engaged in amorous pursuits at the time, just as the excerpt I gave from the Padma Purana says.

Comment: amorous pursuits? The Tirupati Balaji link you've given says that Shiva was absorbed in deep meditation when Bhrigu visited him.

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran I based my answer on the excerpt I gave from the Uttara Kanda of the Padma Purana, not on the Wikipedia article on Venkateshwara.  But in any case, I just edited my answer to include an excerpt from G.V. Chalapathi Rao's translation of the Tirumala Sthala Purana that shows that the Wikipedia article is wrong.

Comment: ha ha! nice for pointing out how online sources like wikipedia can not be always trusted.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan- Is this story also mentioned in Bhrigu samhita?

Comment: @Creator Bhrigu is the author of the Bhrigu Samhita, but he doesn't talk about his life story and the like in that work.  The Bhrigu Samhita is an astrological work.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This story happened at onset this (28th) kaliyuga. But Lord Shiva was worshiped in linga form at Rameswaram by Lord Rama in 24th Tretayuga. I think "story of Brahma and vishnu fighting & Shiva appears as column of Light " would be the best explanation.

Comment: @AnilKumar Let's distinguish two things.  There is the reason why Shiva is worshipped as a Linga at all, which is the Jyotirlinga story you mentioned, and then there is the reason why he's limited to being worshipped as a Linga, which is the curse of Bhrigu that happened in the present Kali Yuga.  By the way, you can see a picture of the original Jyotirlinga that was involved in Brahma and Vishnu's contest in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6512/36

Comment: @AnilKumar Regarding the Rameshwaram lingam, I'm not sure if it has a basis in Hindu scripture.  It's certainly not mentioned in the Ramayana, but it's possible that it's mentioned in the Shiva Purana or one of the other Puranas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan do curses Gods  incurred have anything to do with ordinary people? For eg: Lord Brahma was cursed not to worship .what happens if someone worships him? And there are some temples for Lord Brahma. Similarly what happens if i worship Shiva in idol form? Won't Lord Brahma able to listen my prayers if i worship him,due to Shiva's curse?

Comment: @AnilKumar It's now a sin to worship Brahma outside of Yagnas, and to worship Shiva outside his Linga form.  There are one or two Brahma temples, but they're an exception to this rule, because they have very specific stories about why you're allowed to worship Brahma there.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Shiva Purana mentions how Shiva first came in front of Vishnu and Brahma in Linga form. It is better to post nothing than to post nonsense like 'amorous'.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I'm not talking about the origin of the Linga, I'm talking about why Shiva is only worshipped in Linga form as opposed to idol form.  In any case, I'm not just making things up, I'm just relaying what the Padma Purana says.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan If that is what Padma Puran says then it is no puran at all. This has 100% been added by people who hate Lord Shiva.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I don't think it was added by Shiva-haters - when the gods behave on humanlike ways, that is just the divine Lila.  In any case, the story of Bhrigu's test is mentioned in numerous scriptures; it is the initiating event in the story of Venkateshwara (aka Balaji or Srinivasa).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Or maybe Lord Shiva wanted every being to worship him in only linga form because linga represents infinite Brahman.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, the only explanation given in Hindu scripture for why Shiva is not worshipped in idol form is the Bhrigu test explanation, so I think it's the correct explanation, especially considering the important role Bhrigu's test plays in the story of Venkateshwara.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That's fine, the scriptures are good for reading, the real purpose behind that curse might be different. As I said, it could have some link with Brahman.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, I generally assume scripture is correct unless there's a strong reason to believe it's an interpolation, and in this case it's very unlikely to be an interpolation for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I never said it was an interpolation. The curse is also true and my assumption might also be true.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yeah, there could be multiple reasons why something is the case.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Apart from Shiva being Brahman, IMO initially when Brahma was mulling over how to replicate species he created,Shiva (Shiva-Shakti) separated from his SHAKTI and gave that Shakti to species  to copulate ( Shakti=energy of Copulation) and replicate. So Siva and Shivaa represents COSMIC UNION and thus they(SHIVA) are worshiped collectively as "LINGA AND YONI". Later Shakti reincarnated in human form and married Shankara. This might be the reason why Shiva is worshiped (mainly) for marriage and  fertility problems.

Comment: @AnilKumar Brahma didn't create Shiva, it was Shiva who created both Brahma and Vishnu.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria i didn't say Brahma created Shiva (there's comma), Brahma created species and he had a trouble how to replicate them. Then Shiva separated his Shakti and gave it to species. When Brahma asked Shiva to create, Shiva created people like him "RUDRAS". And even Vaishnava Puranas say Brahma created RUDRA and thus they are in accordance with Shaiva Puranas

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan and others, please note that Lord Shiva is not worshipped **only** in the form of Linga. Despite the story involving sage Bhrigu's curse, Lord Shiva is worshiped in the Linga form **only** in moolastanams. In fact there are many temples such as Kanchi Sri Ekamreshvara temple where the Lord Shiva is worshiped in human form behind the Linga. Also Lord Shiva is worshiped in human form as utsava murthi in all the temples. The story of Bhrgu's curse is there in Puranas, but in reality we find Lord Shiva is worshiped in human form as utsava murthi. - to be contd in the next comment

Comment: The curse doesn't include this exception, so that raises a question about the story. Also the same story says the sage Bhrgu pronounced a curse on Brahma that he would not be worshiped. But in temples built using Shaiva agama rules, you will always see a sannidhi for Brahma on the right side of Lord Shiva's moolastanam. Making offerings to Brahma may or may not be done by the priests, and I am not sure about that.
Some scholars take the story of Bhrgu pronouncing curse as an interpolation, and indication of the age old schism between Shaivaites and Vaishnavas. That is also a plausible theory.

Comment: So considering the fact that Lord Shiva is worshiped in human form, and also as Sri Dakshinamurthi, Lord Nataraja, Virabhadra, Sri Kala Bhairava. Bhikshadana Murthi, eka-pada-murthi, eka-pada-trimurthi, ardhanarishvara - all considered to be different forms of Lord Shiva, makes me take the concept involving the **pillar of jyoti** as the most **conflict free** explanation of Shiva Lingam. The reference quoted from Sri mahA nArAyanOpanisad also adds to the plausibility of this notion, along with the story in Kena upanisad (though it does not mention the words Shiva or Linga).

Answer (score 10):

I will try to answer the question what exactly Shiva Linga means. Hopefully this will answer your question as well.

I am copy-pasting from a blog I wrote about Shiva Linga-

Shiva Linga means “Shiva’s Symbol”. Here Shiva refers to Para-Brahman. Adi Shankara defines the word Shiva as “the very nature of Chit & Anand”. Hence, Shiva refers to Para-Brahman, who is One without a second, without form and without attributes. And this Nirguna Brahman is worshiped through a symbol- the Linga. Further, the Linga is not only a Symbol of Para-Brahman, it is Brahman itself. Linga Purana says “Lingas sakshaan Maheshwarah”. In other-words, Shiva Linga is Para-Brahman itself which is available as Linga (Saguna Brahman) for worship.

The Shiva Linga can be divided into two portions-

1. The vertical Shaft that is called as Linga
2. The Horizontal Platform that is called as Yoni or Adishtana

There are broadly three ways in which the symbolism of Linga and Yoni and their mutual relationship can be understood-

1. The more popular understanding is that, the Yoni or pedastal represents Shakti and the Linga/Shaft represents Shiva- “linga vedi mahadevi lingam sakshat maheshwarah”. Hence, Shiva Linga denotes the Union of Shiva-Shakti or Purusha-Prakriti. Hence, Shiva-Linga as a whole is Para-Brahman itself who is depicted in his Saguna aspect as Shiva & Shakti in Cosmic Union.
2. According to another interpretation, the Shaft/Linga portion is called as “Rudra Bhaga”, the Adhishtana portion is called as Vishnu Bhaga and the portion hidden below the Pedastal is called as Brahma-Bhaga. Hence, Shiva-Linga as a whole represents Para-Brahman itself which manifests as the trinity in Saguna aspect. Upanishads say that the Universe is born out of Brahman, is sustained in Brahman and finally dissolves in Brahman. Hence, Shiva Linga represents Para-Brahman who is creator (Brahma), sustainer (Vishnu) & destroyer (Rudra) of Universe. Linga purana also says that “layanaal lingam ity uktam”.
3. The third interpretation is a Samkhyan interpretation. According to this view, “Linga” is another name for Prakriti or Pradhana. Hence, the Shaft/Linga represents Prakriti and the Adhishtana represents Purusha. This Purusha is called as “Lingin”- the bearer/supporter of Linga/Prakriti. In Vedanta, the Prakriti is called “Maya” and is described as “Ishwara-Aashrita” i.e. supported by Ishwara. Hence, Shiva Linga as a whole represents Para-Brahman in Saguna aspect as Purusha who is bearer of Prakriti or Shiva/Ishwara who is bearer of Shakti/Maya. The Shaft portion signifies that the whole Universe which is Prakriti is born out of & sustained in Brahman, who is the substratum of Universe.

Hence, in all three interpretations, the imagery of Shiva-Linga represents Para-Brahman who is Nirguna & beyond perception but has himself manifested as Linga- a perceivable form (i.e. as Saguna). It is to be noted that the interpretation of Linga=Phallus and Yoni=Vagina has practical application only in certain Tantric Sadhanas like Shiva lata mudra. In such Sadhanas, the Sadhaka self identifies himself with Bhairava & his partner with Bhairavi. And their Sexual Union leads to Samadhi. Only in such Sadhana, that the first symbolism of Cosmic Union of Shiva & Shakti translates practically into Sexual Union of Bhairava & Bhairavi.

Link to the blogpost- [nithinsridhar](https://nithinsridhar.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/random-musings-part-32-the-worship-of-shiva-linga/)

Answer (score 7):

I am giving rough translation from Hindi Version of [Shiva Mahapuran](http://vedpuran.net/2011/10/21/ved_puran/) as published by Geeta press here.

> Sages said:- Everywhere the deities are worshipped only in their
>   image. How is that Shiva is worshipped both in the image and the
>   linga?
>
> Suta said:- O sages, this question is holy and wondrous. Here the
>   speaker is Siva Himself and not any ordinary person. I shall tell you
>   what Shiva Himself had said and what I heard from my own preceptor.
>   Shiva alone is Niskala (nameless and formless) since He is identical
>   with supreme Brahman. **He is also Sakala as He has an embodied form. He
>   is both Sakala and Niskala. It is his Niskala aspect that the Linga is
>   appropriate.** In the Sakala aspect the worship of His embodied form is
>   appropriate. Since He has the Sakala and Niskala aspects He is
>   worshipped both in the linga and in the embodied form by the people
>   and is called the highest Brahman. Other deities, not being Brahman,
>   have no Niskala aspect anywhere. Hence the deities are not worshipped
>   in the formless linga symbol. The other deities are both non-Brahman
>   and individual souls. In view of their being embodied alone they are
>   worshipped solely in the bodily form. Sankara has Brahmatatva and the
>   others Jivatva. This has been explained in the meaning of the Pranava
>   (Om), the essence of Vedanta, by Nandikesvara when asked by
>   Sanatkumara, the intelligent son of Brahma, at the mountain Mandara.
>
> Sanatkumara said:- The embodied form alone is observed in the worship
>   of the deities other than Shiva. But both the Linga and the embodied
>   forms are seen only in the worship of Shiva. Hence O benevolent one,
>   please tell me precisely making me understand the truth.
>
> Nandikeshvara said:- It is impossible to answer the question without
>   revealing the secret of Brahman. O sinless one, since you are pious I
>   shall tell you what Shiva Himself has said. Since Shiva has the
>   bodiless aspect in virtue of His being Supreme Brahman, the Nisakal
>   Lingam, in conformity with the Vedic implication, is used only in His
>   worship. Since He has an embodied form as well, His embodied form is
>   also worshipped and accepted by all people. According to the decision
>   done in the Vedas, the embodied form alone is to be used in the
>   worship of other deities who are individual souls embodied. Devas have
>   only the embodied aspect in their manifestation. In sacred literature,
>   both the Linga and the embodied forms are mentioned for Shiva.
>
> **Lord Shiva said:- Since the Linga rose high resembling a mountain of
>   fire, this shall be famous as Arunachal (Aruna, means “first light or first fire” and Achal, means “mountain”)  mountains. Many holy centers
>   will spring up here. A residence or death in this holy place ensures
>   liberation.**
>
> **I have two forms : the manifest and the unmanifest. Dear sons, first in the form of the column of fire and
>   afterwards in this embodied form I have expounded to you my formless
>   Brhman-hood and embodied Ishwar-hood.**
>
> I am the Supreme Brahman. My form is both manifest and unmanifest in
>   view of Brahman-hood and Ishvatva. My duty is blessing etc., O Brahma
>   and Vishnu, **I am Brahman because of Brhatva(huge size) and
>   Brmhanatva(causing to grow)**.O children,similarly I am atman due to
>   Samatva(equality) and Vyapakatva (pervasiveness). There are five
>   activities in respect of the universe beginning with
>   Anugraha(liberation) and ending with Sarga(creation). Therefore, these
>   activities devolve on me because I am Ishwara and not on anyone else.

[image]
                              [Arunachal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arunachala) or Mountain of first Fire/Light

[image]

Agni Linga/Mountain of Fire

[image]

Swayambhu(self-formed) Linga at Amarnath

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The Linga form is believed to be introduced by Lord Shiva himself, to settle the dispute among Lord Vishnu and Lord Brahma. This is a brief narration of the incident that jabahar has mentioned in [his answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/819/81).

Once, Lord Vishnu and Lord Brahma were fighting over each other's supremacy. Worried by the intense fight between them, Shiva decided to make them realize the futility of their fight. He took the form of a flaming pillar (linga) between Brahma and Vishnu, challenging both of them to measure the gigantic Linga. They accepted the challenge and decided to find one end each to establish supremacy over the other.

Vishnu took the form of a Varaha (boar) and went into the earth (patala loka) to find the bottom end of the Linga. Brahma assumed the form of a swan and flew up to find the top end of the Linga. Even after a very long journey, they were not able to find the end of the Linga.

On his way upward, the exhausted Brahma met a Ketaki flower which fell from the Linga. Brahma got the flower to agree to support his claim of having seen the top of the Linga. Then Brahma descended and met Vishnu and lied to him that he has reached the top. As agreed, the Ketaki flower also supported Brahma's claim.

The unethical act of Brahma enraged Lord Shiva and he appeared with his full glory from the central part of the pillar. Overawed by Lord Shiva's magnificence, Vishnu and Brahma bowed before him. However, the enraged Shiva cursed Brahma, that would never be worshipped nor would he have any temples. Shiva also banned Ketaki flower from being used in any worship as an offering to the gods. Shiva, impressed by Vishnu's perseverance, granted him a status equal to that of himself.

Since Lord Shiva manifested himself in the Linga form, Shiva is widely worshipped as a Lingam.

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked in Shiva Purana, Vidyesvarasamhita, Chapter 5. The answer, after removing the sectarian claims, is that the Saivites use the linga form to signify nameless and formless aspects of the deity.

I am posting the quote (I changed the word phallus into the more appropriate linga):

> Sages said:- 8. Everywhere the deities are worshipped only in their
>   image. How is that Siva is worshipped both in the image and the linga?
>
> Suta said:- 9. O sages, this question is holy and wondrous. Here the speaker is Siva Himself and not any ordinary person.
>   10. I shall tell you what Siva Himself had said and what I heard from my own preceptor. Siva alone is Niskala (nameless and formless) since He is identical with supreme Brahman.
>   11. He is also Sakala as He has an embodied form. He is both Sakala and Niskala. It is his Niskala aspect that the Linga is appropriate. 12-13. In the Sakala aspect the worship of His embodied form is appropriate. Since He has the Sakala and Niskala aspects He is worshipped both in the linga and in the embodied form by the people and is called the highest Brahman. Other deities, not being Brahman, have no Niskala aspect anywhere. 14. Hence the deities are not worshipped in the formless linga symbol. The other deities are both non-Brahman and individual souls. 15. In view of their being embodied alone they are worshipped solely in the bodily form. Sankara has Brahmatatva and the others Jivatva. 16. This has been explained in the meaning of the Pranava (Om), the essence of Vedanta, by Nandikesvara when asked by Sanatkumara, the intelligent son of Brahma, at the mountain Mandara.

Comment: Your answer has become a subset of [Ravi J's answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11137/1049). However he posted just recently, while yours was quite early.

Comment: Is it written in the Shiva Purana that if  a girl worship Linga, she will get good husband?

Answer (score 3):

*Worship of Shiva , as a Yogi,and His Vahana, the Bull ,predates Buddhism*.These images are found in Indus valley Civilization,which existed between 2500 BC to 2000 BC .
 The symbols of *Linga and Yoni* , are much older . These are worshipped as the God & Goddess of Fertility ,by aboriginal tribes ,all over the World---representing *Sexual Intercourse*.
 Philosophical meanings , have been assigned to these Symbols , *by different Civilizations ,at different times*.
 Will Durant , has studied these aspects in his book--The History of Civilizations.
Carl Jung – the Psychologist,has studied the meanings of *different Religious Symbols and their inspirational values*.
 One explanation,that I heard in a religious discourse ,linked it to the *Adwaita Vedanta*. **Adwaita** , means literally--*not Two*.So  it is **one (or/and) zero** .
**The Linga is the sybol of one .The cross section is a circle ,representing zero**.
 ***GOD is either ONE or ZERO ( Sunya or Space)***

Answer (score 1):

The word "Lingam" or "Linga" means "Symbol." 'Siva," in addition to other meanings, means "Great." Thus, "Sivalingam" means "Great Symbol."

Sivalingams are found in both Saiva and Vaishnava Temples. Mostly, it is either a circular base part with a cylindrical  upright stump in the centre or a square with a cylindrical  upright stump at the centre. In both cases, combined figure symbolizes "the Middle Path.

"The Middle Path is the fundamental philosophy of Buddhism. It is the Buddhist Dhamma. Here a question may be asked: What has "the Middle Path" to do with Siva and Vishnu? Actually both Siva and Vishnu are the imaginary creations based on Buddha and his Preaching!

To understand this, one must have a thorough knowledge on Symbolization and Symbolization of Buddha and Buddhism. Vishnu holds a conch by his left hand and rotates a circular disc by his right forefinger. What do these two symbolize severally and jointly? Our "learned" will come with something told in Puranas!

A conch makes sound that could be heard by everyone without any discrimination. Therefore a conch could symbolize making a public announcement or preaching something to all. Now the question arises as what is preached by Vishnu.

The answer is given by the rotating circular disc. A circular disc rotated by the forefinger symbolizes the Middle Path. Therefore Vishnu is a person who preached the Middle Path to all. Again a question arises as what type of person Vishnu is. Vishnu has a "U' mark placed symmetrically above his nose.

This also symbolizes Middle Path. Therefore Vishnu is a one who adheres to the Muddle Path and Preaches others to practice the Middle Path. Buddha was the only person who adhered to the Middle Path and preached all to practice the Middle Path. Therefore Vishnu is an imaginary creation based on Buddha and Buddhism!

Likewise Siva also carries a hand drum, Tri-suula and burning flame. He has Triple stripe on his forehead. Hand drum sumbolizes preaching something to all. Tri - Suula has its two outer limbs curved outside pointing the opposite directions.

The muddle one is straight. Therefore Tri - suula symbolizes the Middle Path. Burning flame symbolizes light or Enlightenment. The Triple stripe also symbolizes the Middle Path. Therefore Siva is also a person who adheres to the Middle Path and Preach the Middle Path to all that produces Enlightenment! Thus, Siva is also an imaginary creation based on Buddha and Buddhism.

So the Sivalingams could be placed in bith Saiva and Vaishnava Temples. In the Vaishnava temples of Ariyaluur, Kaaramadau, Mondippaalayam, Thirumarugalin South India, we find Sivalingams.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! you should cite sources for your answer.

Comment: Worship of *Shiva , as a Yogi,and His Vahana, the Bull* ,predates Buddhism.These *images* are found in *Indus valley Civilization*,which existed between *2500 BC to 2000 BC* .<br/> The *symbols of Linga and Yoni , are much older* . These are worshipped as the *God & Goddess of Fertility ,by aboriginal tribes ,all over the World---representing Sexual Intercourse*.<br> Philosophical meanings , have been assigned to these Symbols , by different Civilizations ,at different times.<br/> Will Durant , has studied these aspects in his book--**The History of Civilizations**.<br/>Ref. also-Carl Jung

Answer (score 1):

In a cross-referential way, I think that the content of this website
https://thetemplescience.blogspot.com/2019/08/shiva-lingam-scientific-truth-mysterious-facts-and.html?m=1

might answer the question about Shiva Lingam Shape and Form:

" Hinduism says, the Shiva Lingam is the symbol of Nothigness which later manifested as the Universe. According to Hindu Science the hiranyagarbha  or the cosmic golden egg came from infinite Shiva Lingam. Now coincidentally the modern scientists are referring an image of our Universe which is exactly the mirror image of hiranyagarbha (cosmic egg) or Shiva Lingam. Shiva Lingam represents the shape of entire cosmos. By decoding the data gathered by  NASA’s WMAP (Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe measured the fluctuations in the cosmic microwave background radiations) satellite Italian scientists proposed a overall shape of our Universe. Which is just a mirror image of ellipsoidal or egged shaped natural Shiva lingam or generally called “Bana lingam” available in the bay of Narmada river. Science confirms that the Universe might be oval shaped. "

Worshipping Shiva Lingam it is exactly equiparable to recollect the Universal Form within us.

Imagine Shiva is non-locality yet multi-locality at the same time.

And such is the Universe. Its shape is ovoidal- toroidal.

In a frontal perspective it is exactly that of the Shiva Lingam.

Vishnu and Brahma are both contained inside the Lingam, but we cannot see them, in particular not The Brahma.

That is why we do not see worshipping idols of the Brahma so often.

That is why we are worshipping the Shiva Lingam.

Shiva indeed appeared as a fire or a beam light (like that of a nuclear reactor or even more).

Creation has a lot to do with that, if one think that Shiva is Hiranyagarbha.

According to these scientific and religious researches of that website, it results clear why Shiva appeared in the form of Linga.

And because He is Nirguna, he is Swayambhoo and He is changeable in nature, he is Sound, Rythm and He is also Digambaraia (all the directions are like His dresses) it means that Shiva is The Universe.

Hence the other Gods worship themselves as reflection into Him and see Him as the Universe from where they are coming from.

Someone here in a previous answer intelligently stated that Time is not knowable really, and that's why our time calculations are always delusional.
Because Shiva is also Mahakal, such as Maa Kali is the same (and Maa Dhoomavati also).

Shiva is beyond Time. He is Timeless.

And also Universe (scientifical by the partial Western science, so re-explained with big calculations and headhaches proofs) it is Timeless.

Om Namah ShiVaYa

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**: Manifestation begins with the union of cit:śakti and cit:ānanda. This union is called “Liṅga” or an ellipsoid (representing a perpetual motion in the shape of an egg). From this (union of cit:śakti - cit:ānanda), all manifestation/change goes into a loop of perpetual motion.

**Vedic origin of the term Liṅga**: a term that was first associated with Rudra/Siva in Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Aranyaka 10.16.1-2 with the homage “sivaya namaha, sivalingaya namaha”.

> Urdhvāya Namaha| Urdhvaliṅgāya Namaha| hiranyana Namaha|
> hiranyaliṅgāya namaha| suvarnāya namaha| survarnaliṅgāya namaha|
> divyāya namaha| divyaliṅgāya namaha| bhavāya namaha| bhavaliṅgāya
> namaha| sarvāya namaha| sarvaliṅgāya namaha| sivāya namaha|
> sivaliṅgāya namaha| jvalāya namaha| jvalaliṅgāya namaha| atmāyanamaha
> atmaliṅgāya namaha| paramāya namaha| paramaliṅgāya namaha.
> Etathsomasya suryasya sarvalingam sthāpāyati pānimantram pavitram||
>
> Kṛṣṇa Yajur Vedā Taittirīya Aranyaka 10.16.1-2

**Definition of Liṅga**: Liṅga is a arūparūpi (a:rūpa:rūpi), meaning a contradiction having a form (rūpa) and, at the same time, not confined to any specific form (a:rūpa). Since this union of cit:śakti and cit:ānanda is the first act, a Liṅga denotes a sign or first signal/act, the first union āliṅgana – which is called sandhi/yoga. Further, Liṅga is the first duality, a duality of gender (pu:liṅga, stri:linga), the innate Brahman ātmaliṅga TA10.16.2, a phallus (male organ holding Tejas, or union of species) and origin. Some scholars also consider Liṅga as an iconification of the pineal gland due to its association with metaphysical potential. Please note, when we say phallus, we should not limit Liṅga to only being a human reproductive organ, why? That would be like saying that the Supreme Brahman, before the creation of realities, first thought of a human reproductive organ, how is that sensible? Sages noticed the pattern of this union in everything, from the cosmic union to the union of beings on Earth, and realized the phallus in the same sense, without the notion of embarrassment/shyness or apprehension, the Gudimallam Linga is a perfect example which dates back to 1st Century BCE. Many temples (consecrated spaces) were also built to exhibit this sacred union without reluctance or insecurity.

Everything in Creation – from the largest to the tiniest – is forever in a perpetual motion (Śakti) of manifestation (Viṣṇu) and dissolution/implosion back into the source (Śiva). From this ellipsoid emerges a pulse in the form of a roar, this roar is called Rudra – which is very similar to the concept of Sabda: Brahman of Yoga and the Upaniṣhads. Across the Vedās, Rudra always encompasses a dual and contradictory role. The word Rudra also means to weep, as Sāyaṇācārya, the magnificent commentator of the Vedās says, “the one who makes our enemies weep”, or the very affirmation of Him being auspicious (Śiva) RV 10.92/KV4.5.10.

Mahābhāratam Itihasa Drona Parva, Narayanastra-mokshana Parva, Section 203 says:

> Vyasa says: Since he Great and Ancient and is the source of Life and
> its continuance, and since his Phallic emblem is everlasting he is for
> that reason called Sthānu. He who adoreth any image of the Phallic
> emblem of that high-souled God always obtain great prosperity by that
> act
>
> Mahābhāratam Itihasa Drona Parva, Narayanastra-mokshana Parva, Section
> 203

For the detailed article please search in Google for "Sanatanadhara Śiva / Rudrā across Vedās to Itihāsa"