# Which scriptures describe Vināyaka as son of Nandi?

Tags: ganesha, shaivism, shaiva-siddhanta, nandi

Shaiva Siddhanta is based on the Shaiva Agamas and the poems of the 63 Nāyanārs . One of those 63 Nāyanārs is Saint Tirumūlar and also one of the 18 Siddhars and also a Yogi himself. His work [Tirumantiram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirumantiram) is the tenth of the twelve volumes of the Tirumurai, the key texts of Shaiva Siddhanta. He is the first one to use to the term *Shaiva Siddhanta* in his works.  My question is not about the text but the invocatory verse to Vināyaka.

In the English translation to  Tirumūlar's work Tirumantiram, there is an invocatory verse to Ganesha, it is:

[Original verse](https://shaivam.org/thirumurai/tenth-thirumurai/298/thirumoolar-nayanar-thirumandiram-payiram-kadavul-vazhthu) in Tamil (Thanks to TheDestroyer for finding it)

> விநாயகர் காப்பு 
>   ஐந்து கரத்தனை யானை முகத்தனை 
>   இந்தின் இளம்பிறை போலும் எயிற்றனை 
>   **நந்தி மகன்தனை** ஞானக் கொழுந்தினைப் 
>   புந்தியில் வைத்தடி போற்றுகின் றேனே.
>
> Vināyakar kāppu
>   aintu karattaṉai yāṉai mukattaṉai
>   intiṉ iḷampiṟai pōlum eyiṟṟaṉai
>   **nanti makaṉtaṉai** ñāṉak koḻuntiṉaip
>   puntiyil vaittaṭi pōṟṟukiṉ ṟēṉē.

In the [English translation](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/tirumantiram) to  Tirumūlar's work Tirumantiram, there is an invocatory verse to Ganesha, it is:

> He who has the five hands and the elephant's face,
>   Whose tusk is even as the crescent moon,
>   **The son of Nandi**, the Flower of Wisdom,
>   Him I cherish in thought, His feet adore.

[image]

There is already a question about Ganesha having five hands - [What scriptures describe Ganesha having five hands?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16621/5212)

Question:

- Why is Vināyaka called as Son of Nandi here?

Comment: The image is from which book?

Comment: @Rickross It is the online translation of Tirumantiram  https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/tirumantiram. I downloaded a pdf version.

Comment: @SreeCharan Ok. Thanks . Just yesterday rakesh joshi gave me the link of this website. Nice website.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: Please read this story (http://thewheeloflearning.blogspot.com/2015/10/14-goddess-malini-and-birth-of-ganesha.html).  It was saying that Ganesha was born to Malini, an elephant headed goddess.