# What is the difference between a Shiva temple and a Jyotirlinga?

Tags: shiva, temple, jyotirlinga

Spread across India, we have many temples of Lord Shiva and we also have about twelve Jyotirlingas.

I want to know whether there's any difference between a Shiva Temple and a Jyotirlinga.

Comment: difference as in what? can you be more specific please..

Comment: Difference as in Worship,Importance...

Comment: _Jyotirlinga_ is said to be part of soul of lord Shiva himself in a _linga_ form.

Comment: Jyotirlingas are 12 special temples where Supreme God Shiva pierced the three worlds appearing as a huge Infinite Pillar of Light, the Jyotirlinga which later cooled into the Holy Mountain Annamalai (on which the Temple of Arunachaleshvara is located). The jyothirlinga shrines are Temples where Shiva appeared as a fiery column of light. The first Jyotirlinga is Nageshwar. It is located in Gujarat. Generally, faith need not be dependent on these factors, yet appearance of Shiva in these temples holds importance.

Answer (score 13):

## What is a Shiva Temple?

Shiva Temples are specially designed places of worship where the presiding deity is Lord Shiva in the form of a *Linga*.

---

## What is a *Linga*?

*Linga* is an aniconic representation of Lord Shiva, which is used for worship in temples. To know more about a *Linga*, you can refer [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/101/4459)

---

## What is a *Jyotirlinga*?

*Jyothirlinga*s are twelve <sup>1</sup> specially consecrated *linga*s present in the world. [*The Shiva Purana*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bchgql0em9YC) deals with *Jyothirlinga*s in detail. It is believed that Shiva first manifested himself as a *Jyotirlinga* on the night of the *Arudra* festival, thus the special reverence for the *Jyotirlinga*. The legend behind this is mentioned in the *Shiva Purana* and is beautifully explained in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3284/4459).

**Etymology of the Word** - The word *Jyothirlinga* is made up of two words, *Jyoti* meaning 'radiance' and *Linga*, which represents Lord Shiva.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>As Keshav mentions in a [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/what-is-the-difference-between-a-temple-and-a-jyotirlinga/10719#comment25566_10719) below, there are actually many more Jyothirlingas, but these 12 are the most famous amongst them. The exact number is put at 64 in a few texts</sub>

---

## What is the difference between a Shiva *Linga* and *Jyothirlinga*?

As mentioned earlier the main difference is that *jyothirlinga*s are twelve special *linga*s (mentioned in *Shiva Purana*). Shiva *Linga*s are a form of Lord Shiva which are found in many Shiva Temples.

The relation can be explained by stating the the *Jyothirlinga*s are an enumerated sub set of 12 different elements of the countably infinite set of all *Linga*s in the world.

---

## Who mentioned about *Jyothirlinga*s?

*Jagadguru Sri Shankaracharya* mentioned the twelve *Jyothirlinga*s in a 13 stanza verse with 1 stanza dedicated to each of the *Jyothirlinga*s and 1 concluding stanza. He also wrote a shortened form, which can be translated as follows

> Saurāṣṭre Somanāthaṃ ca Śrīśaile Mallikārjunam
>   Ujjayinyāṃ Mahākālam Omkāram Mamleśhwaram
>   Paraly Vaidyanāthaṃ cha Ḍākinyāṃ Bhīmaśhaṅkaram
>   Setubandhe tu Rāmeśaṃ Nāgeśhaṃ Dārukāvane
>   Vārāṇasyāṃ tu Viśveśaṃ Tryambakaṃ Gautamītaṭe
>   Himālaye tu Kedāraṃ Ghuśmeśaṃ ca Śivālaye
>   etāni jyotirliṅgāni sāyaṃ prātaḥ paṭhennaraḥ
>   saptajanmakṛtaṃ pāpaṃ smaraṇena vinaśyati

The verse can be translated in English as

> Somanath in Saurashtra and Mallikarjunam in Shri-Shailam
>   Mahakaal in Ujjain, Mamleshwar in Omkareshwar
>   Vaidyanath in Chitaobhoomi, Jharkhand or Parali in Maharasthra and Bhimashankaram in Dakinya
>   Ramesham (Rameshwaram) in Sethubandh, Nagesham in Daruka-Vana
>   Vishwa-Isham (Vishvanath) in Vanarasi, Triambakam at bank of the river Gautami;(Godavari)
>   Kedar (Kedarnath) in Himalayas and Grushnesh (Gushmeshwar) in Shivalaya (Shiwar)
>   One who recites these Jyotirlingas every evening and morning
>   is relieved of all sins committed in past seven lives.

<sub>(Transliteration and Translation taken from the Wikipedia page on [*Jyothirlinga*s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyotirlinga#Sanskrit_Sloka))</sub>

---

## Where are the *Jyothirlinga*s present?

Name of *Jyothirlinga* | State     ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​      ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ |  Location
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Somnath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somnath) ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​​ ​ ​| Gujrat  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​   ​| [Prabhas Patan](https://goo.gl/maps/2vshBetFdjH2)
[Mallikarjuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallikarjuna_Jyotirlinga) ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​  ​| Andhra Pradesh ​ ​  | [Srisailam](https://goo.gl/maps/DRRPb78mtSQ2)
[Mahakaleshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahakaleshwar_Jyotirlinga)  ​ ​ ​ ​ ​  ​​  ​ ​ | Madhya Pradesh | [Ujjain](https://goo.gl/maps/hE3qJUwt72A2)
[Omkareshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omkareshwar)  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​  ​  ​ ​​ ​ | Madhya Pradesh | [Mandatha](https://goo.gl/maps/zJ3F8EEovYs)
[Vaidyanath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baidyanath_Temple)*  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​   ​ | Jharkhand  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ ​ ​| [Deoghar](https://goo.gl/maps/xgGCtP7smuu)
[Bhimashankar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhimashankar_Temple)*  ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​  ​ ​​ ​ | Maharashtra  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​| [Khed](https://goo.gl/maps/xkaknwKaLTw)
[Rameshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanathaswamy_Temple)  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​  ​​​ ​ | Tamil Nadu  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​   | [Rameshwaram](https://goo.gl/maps/QscQMMKjjS22)
[Nageshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aundha_Nagnath_Temple)*   ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ | Maharastra  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​   | [Aundha](https://goo.gl/maps/kaTiyHRHFK52)
[Vishwanath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashi_Vishwanath_Temple)  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​ ​ | Uttar Pradesh  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​  ​    | [Varanasi](https://goo.gl/maps/U932G3FrG8M2)
[Tryambakeshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimbakeshwar_Shiva_Temple)​ ​  ​ ​ ​ ​  | Maharashtra  ​   ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​    | [Nashik](https://goo.gl/maps/trsqz4BDrNq)
[Kedarnath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kedarnath_Temple)  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​  ​ | Uttarakhand    ​  ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​    | [Garhwal](https://goo.gl/maps/HVeFcsX2A1n)
[Grishneshwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grishneshwar)*  ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​   ​ ​ ​| Maharashtra  ​ ​ ​ ​  ​ ​ ​  ​   | [Daulatabad](https://goo.gl/maps/JUmQF6awenr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
* <sub>Places are disputed and no conclusion has been drawn.</sub>

An image of the 12 *Jyothirlinga* temples on a map can be seen below

[image: Image of Jyothirlingas]

<sub>Image from [Shiv Parvati Sewa Dal, Chandigarh](http://www.shivparvatisewadal.com/)</sub>

Comment: There are actually many more than 12 Jyotirlingas, those 12 are just the most famous.  (It's just like people make list of Vishnu's "top ten" avatarams, even though he's incarnated countless times.) In fact the original Jyotirlinga, the one where Brahma and Vishnu had their contest, is in the Arunachala hill; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6512/36

Comment: Yep. There are a few places where it is mentioned that there are 64. I'm still looking for credible sources. (And the list of those 64)

Comment: @BhargavRao Some jyotirlingas are present in Amaravati (Indra's Place), Patala and other regions. See Skanda Purna.

Answer (score 7):

**Difference**

Yes there is a difference between a Lord Shiva temple and a [Jyotirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyotirlinga). It is said that Lord Shiva himself is present there at all 12 Jyotirlings where as in temples we do establishment( स्थापना)of a Lord Shiva murti as an idol or a shiv linga and start doing prayers and performing all the rituals. No Jyotirling was established by us, it was all already established by Lord Shiva himself.

**Importance**

Each and every Jyotirling has its own importance, check the links to get the details as it would be a too long answer to post importance of each jyotirling

1. [Somnath](http://www.boldsky.com/yoga-spirituality/faith-mysticism/2012/somnath-temple-lord-shiva-jyotirlingas-029424.html)
2. [Mallikarjuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallikarjuna_Swamy#Story)
3. [Mahakaleshwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahakaleshwar_Jyotirlinga#Mythology)
4. [Omkareshwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omkareshwar#Legends_.26_history_of_Omkareshwar)
5. [Kedarnath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kedarnath_Temple#Hindu_mythology)
6. [Bhimashankar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhimashankar#Story_.26_History)
7. [Vishwanath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashi_Vishwanath_Temple#Importance_of_the_temple)
8. [Trimbakeshwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimbakeshwar_Shiva_Temple#In_Mythology.2C_history_and_present)
9. [Baidyanath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baidyanath_Temple#Legend)
10. [Nageshvara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nageshvara_Jyotirlinga#The_narratives_on_Nageshvara_Jyotirlinga)
11. [Rameshwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanathaswamy_Temple,_Rameswaram#Significance_Today)
12. [Grishneshwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grishneshwar#History)

Answer (score 2):

Jyotirlings are place where the Shiva appeared when he had created the jyotirlings initially.

As the mythology suggest there was a argument between the lord Vishnu and lord Brahma over the supremacy. At that time Lord Shiva had created three endless light beams cutting across the three world and asked both the gods to enter in these light beams and one who will find the end would be supreme. Both Lord Vishnu and Lord Brahma enter the light. But none could find the end. Lord Vishnu accepts the defeat and Lord Brahma lied.

Lord Shiva cursed Lord Brahma that he will not have any followers, And He blessed Lord Vishnu that  He will be Prayed till the end of the world. Those three beams of light are original Jyotirlings and the place where the Lord Shiva appeared on the earth during that travel are called jyotirlings there were supposedly 64 jyotirling out of which 12 are very Pious.

For more information read [this](http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/features/04-12/features2427.htm) article published by ISKCON.