# What is a Jyotirling and how it is different from other Shivling?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga

There are 12 Jyotirling of Lord Shiv. I want to know that what is Jyotirling and how these 12 Jyotirling are different from other Shivling?

Comment: Related - [What is the difference between a temple and a Jyotirlinga?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2533/467)