# Why one should not sleep on Shiv-ratri?

Tags: shiva

As we know today its Shivratri and the reason what I know about the reason is if our spine is perpendicular to the planet tonight One's life forces may go higher (tonight our planet is on certain angle), I came to know it from Sadguru of Isha Foundation, Who have a great festival on every Shivratri

How true is that if any one can educate me on that.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Actually, not mere night awakening one must keep his spine erect to get advantages.

Comment: [This](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11858/8883) answer states `The night on this day, when the constellations are in some particular position, is very auspicious for meditation. And so it is very useful for people to keep awake and meditate on Shivaratri`

Comment: It's not that one should not literally sleep, it's more that this night is for the unison of Shiva and Shakti, so one should spend time in meditation. This is similar to the act of *Maata ka jaagran*. And it is very common to not sleep during fasts, to make sure that all your senses are in control.

Comment: @ABcDexter thanks may i know who is shakti

Comment: Everything... She is the feminine, infinite, power which makes not only this visible Universe, but also is the life force who makes sure that things go on as decided according to the cosmic plan. Her forms are many, she is *maaya*, we are nothing but a infinitesimal point in her visualization of Shiva. [Shakti is known by many names](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaaIygLdHdI&t=1055s&list=PLFkMg1BXn_2NYpWpAI2hRdz9Q9U_ry5nI&index=1), Paarvati, Saraswati, Lakshmi, Durga, Kaali to name a few. Her every form is meant to make life stable, so that the cycle of *sansaar* goes on. She is in everyone.