# Maha Shivaratri in Margashira or Magha masa?

Tags: shiva, shivaratri

In this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17728/why-maha-shivaratri-wont-fall-on-karthika-masam?r=SearchResults) it is stated that Shivaratri is celebrated in Margashira masa (Dec). But Shivaratri festival is celebrated in Magha masa (Feb-Mar).

Why the celebration in a different month?

Are there any details on Magha masa celebrations?

Comment: Today (11-Mar-2021) is Maha Shivaratri.. and as per Purinimanta calendera it's Phalguna month krishna paksha...In Amanta calendar, it's Magha masa...Shivaratri comes in every month but Maha Shivaratri comes once in a year..

Comment: Yes, aware about that. Question is about Linga Purana saying Margashira while celebrations in Magha. @yds

Answer (score 8):

As per Naradiya Samhita , Mahashivaratri is celebrated as below:

माघेकृष्णेचतुर्दश्यामादिदेवो महानिशि ।
शिवलिंगतयॊद्भूतः कॊटिसूर्यसमप्रभः ॥

On the 14th day of Magha month, Krishna Paksha, Mahadeva showed himself as shivalinga which was as resplendant as crores of suns. Hence that is the day on which Shivaratri is celebrated with Abhisheka to Shivalinga along with chanting of Rudram !