# On which day/tithi did Shiva-Parvati get married?

Tags: shiva, marriage, shiva-purana, parvati

To my knowledge, it has to be the day of MahaShivaratri when Shiva-Parvati got married. However as per [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17729/647),

> Maha Sivaratri is the night when Lord Shiva appeared as Linga to stop conflict between Brahma and Vishnu

If that is the case, then on which tithi did Shiva Parvati get married?

Answer (score 4):

As per the *Kālikapurāṇa*

> माधवे मासि पञ्चम्यां सिते पक्षे गुरोर्दिने । चन्द्रे चोत्तरफाल्गुन्यां भरण्यादौ स्थिते रवौ ।। आगता मुनयस्तत्र मरीचिप्रमुखा मुहुः । हरेण चिन्तिताः सर्वे तथा ब्रह्मादयः सुराः ।। तथा च सर्वे दिक्पालाः मुनयश्च तपोधनाः । शच्या सह तथा शक्रो ब्रह्माण्याद्यास्तु मातरः । नारदश्च गतस्तत्र  देवर्षिब्रह्मणः सुतः ।। एतैः परिचरैः सार्धं गणैराप्यायितः स्वकैः । वैवाहिकेन विधिना गिरिपुत्रीं हरोऽग्रहीत् ।।
>
> Translation: **On Thursday, the 5th day of the bright half of the fortnight in the month of *Vaiśākha* with the moon in conjunction with *Uttaraphālgunī* & the sun in conjunction with *Bharaṇī***, the leading sages like *Marīci*, all *deva*s beginning
> with *Brahmā*, all lords of the directions, sages who have austerities as their wealth, *Indra* accompanied with *Śacī*, the *mātṛkā*s beginning with *Brahmāṇī* & the celestial sage *Nārada* (who is also) the son of *Brahmā* - all of them arrived on being desired by *Hara*. Accompanied by them as His attendants & His own *gaṇa*s who were well received (by the bride's family), ***Hara* accepted the daughter of the mountains according to the rites of marriage.**[*Kālikapurāṇa*:44:41-44]

If we add 7 days to this tithi, (since the *Śivapurāṇa* quoted in an other answer states that it took 7 days for the *varayātrī*s to reach the venue), we get *Vaiśākha śuklā trayodaśī* as the probable date. This is highly convenient, as *trayodaśī* is the *tithi* dedicated to *Kāma* & on *Caitra śuklā trayodaśī*, *Bhagavāna Śiva* had resurrected *Kāmadeva*.

Comment: nice. So this has no relation to Gangaur? Chaitra Shukla 3. How is this day not commonly celebrated?

Comment: Gangaur is celebrated only in Rajasthan, Punjab & western UP & is virtually unknown outside that region. And according to Tripurarahasya & Devibhagavatam, Bhagavana Siva had 3 wives - Gauri, Sati & Parvati. So it is highly possible that Caitra sukla trtiya is the marriage date of the 1st wife, while the 3rd wife was married in the month of Vaisakha.

Comment: But, this vaishakha day is not celebrated at all. Plus Isn’t 3 wives stretching it? Gauri and Parvati being the same. (Let’s leave out Sati for a moment, though she is the same too).

Answer (score 1):

This can't exactly be considered a definitive answer, but here's what I could find. It's a bit of a roundabout story.

The original Shiva Purana discusses the marriage and courtship of Shiva and Parvati in Section 2.3, which is the *Parvati Khanda* of the *Rudra-saṃhitā.* There are only two references to dates in the whole section. The first comes in Chapter [39, line 16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226103.html), where Shiva tells Narada:

> O Nārada, the marriage will take place after seven days from today. Following the worldly conventions I shall make a grand festival of the same.

Unfortunately, no mention of the current date then is given in that passage, so it turns out not to be so useful.

The other mention is in [Chapter 48](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226112.html#:%7E:text=The%20Shiva%20Purana&text=This%20page%20relates%20%E2%80%9Cdescription%20of,such%20as%20cosmology%20and%20philosophy.), which describes the ceremony itself.
Lines 4/5:

> **4]** Then the brahmins were requested by Himavat:
>
> *“May the rite be formally started after narrating the Tithi etc. The auspicious hour has come.”*
>
> **5]** After saying “*So be it*”, the excellent brahmins who knew the proper time proclaimed the Tithi etc. very delightedly.

There, the tithi is said but not specified. This is the extent of the information in the Shiva Purana.

(The other text that devotes itself to Shiva and Parvati's marriage is the Kumarasambhava by Kalidas, but this is also lacking in the specifics of the tithi.)

Then I found [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Agni_Purana/xJSR4KA3Ac0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=shiva%20marriage%20tithi%20purana&pg=PA63&printsec=frontcover) book about the Agni Purana, where the author writes:

> ﻿The Purana reforms that it was on **the third day of the lunar fortnight**, i.e. 'triteeya' that Lord Shiv married Parvati or Gauri. Rites performed on this day are thus known as 'Gauri Vratha'. Lord Shiv and Gauri have to be given only of the offering of front. On this day eight names, given below, of the Gauri ought to be ritually recited. The names are: Lalita, Viyaya, Bhadra, Bhavani, Kumnda, Shiva, Vasudeni and Gauri.

And in a footnote:

> This information is in the sharp contradiction of the normal schedule. Normally Lord Shiv's marriage day is solemnised on Shivratri day i.e. 14th day of the bright fortnight.

It took a long time to find the actual chapter, but I eventually found it. It's in the [Agni Purana's section about vows to be made on certain days](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083407.html); this one is in the section for vows to be made on the third lunar day:

> **1]** I shall describe the vows (to be practised) on the third lunar day which would confer enjoyment and emancipation. Listen to me. (I shall describe) the mūlagaurīvrata for the (goddess) Lalitā (a form of consort of Śiva) (to be done) on the third lunar day.
>
> **2]** Goddess Gaurī was married by Hara (Śiva) on the third day of the bright (fortnight) in (the month of) caitra (April-May).

It's a little confusing because it says 'marriage by,' but this seems to have been an old variant of 'married to.' The original Sanskrit chapter also says this.

So the answer *seems* to be the third day of the Chaitra month.

A few random notes:

- [This](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Shiv_Purana/bchgql0em9YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=shiva%20parvati%20marry%20tithi%20OR%20titi%20OR%20date%20OR%20month%20OR%20moon%20OR%20day&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover) version of the Shiva Purana says that the chosen day was the thirteenth day, or *trayodashi* of Phalguna. But there's no reference in the actual Purana to support this.
- [This](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kashur_The_Kashmiri_Speaking_People/Bb-QBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=trayodashi%20(13th%20day)%20of%20the%20dark) book on Kashmiri culture says that they, too, celebrate it on *trayodashi*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maha_Shivaratri#:%7E:text=Shivaratri%2C%20regarded%20as%20the%20most,the%20rest%20of%20the%20country.) says that this is a feature of Kashmiri Shaivism.
- The Wikipedia article for Maha Shivaratri, linked above, says that there are a lot of different thoughts about Maha Shivaratri's significance, and one of them is that it marks the anniversary of Shiva and Parvati's marriage. Many other online sources agree.

There may be more to it, or there may not, but that's the best I can do.

Comment: A well researched answer. +1 . I would still wait for more answers to be able to accept one. :)