# How can God be cursed?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, brahma

As I was looking through this question [Why is Shiva primarily worshipped in a linga form?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/101/why-is-only-shiva-worshiped-in-a-linga-form/122#122)
I came across an answer by keshav, where he narrates the story of sage Brighu cursing Brahma and Shiva. We have also read many stories and incidents where God's were being cursed by saints and mortals. Just to note a few, we have the story of Tulasi cursing vishnu and Gandhari cursing krishna.

My question is how can someone curse the supreme being just like that!? Do they have more power and authority over God? Or was it meant to be that way?

Comment: There is no such thing as curse for God. It is all part of his drama. It is like a movie. 'Why did the director allow the hero to be attacked by the villlain? He could have changed the movie so that the Hero always wins'. However nobody will watch such a movie. Similarly the whole of creation is like a giant movie of God. God simply acts and in reality all is God, all are Eternal sparks of Divine. In reality God is Lord Shiva, God is the saint, God is the sage, God is the devotee, God is the villain, God is the inert material also. Sarvam Khalvidam Brahma. All the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

God can be cursed only when He wishes it this way. Here is an example of Narada's curses on Sri Vishnu in a story that took place like this.

There is a story of sage Narada and Vishvamohini. Once Narada, on seeing Vishvamohini, forgot all about his dispassion and thought to devise some means so that the beautiful princess may choose him for her husband. Narada prayed to Sri Hari and requested the God for His own beauty to get possession of Vishvamohini. In the sage's own interest the gracious God had made him ugly (with monkey-like face) beyond description. But no one could mark the change that had taken place in Narada.

Narada went and sat where the arena for the choice-marriage had been prepared. The princess alone saw his ugly form. The moment she beheld his monkey-like face and frightful form she was filled with rage. She moved on to the next and did not care to give even a second look. On seeing his reflection in water, the sage was filled with fury and cursed Sri Hari. This is narrated in Tulasidas' Sri Ramacharitamanas, Balkand ([here](http://web--stock.in/001-Epics-PDF/Ram-Charit-Manas-English/002-Ram-Charit-Manas-English.pdf)-page 101, search page 21). Here is the curse:

> You made me look like a monkey; therefore You shall have monkeys for Your helpmates. And as You have grievously wronged me, so shall You suffer the pangs of separation from Your wife. **Gladly accepting the curse**, the compassionate Lord made many entreaties to the sage, and withdrew the irrestible charm of His Maya. When Sri Hari lifted the spell of His Maya, there was neither Ramaa nor the princess to be seen by His side. In dire dismay the sage then clasped the feet of Hari and said, "O Reliever of the distress of the suppliant, save me! O gracious lord! let my curse prove ineffectual." **"It was My will", replied the Lord**, who is so merciful to the humble.

Therefore, as is evident from the story that God can be cursed only when He wishes to be cursed.

The above incident was one of the reasons responsible for incarnation of Sri Rama. As Sri Rama, Sri Hari suffered separation from His wife (Sri Sita) and had monkeys as His helpmates.

Comment: Convincing answer :) But i have one more doubt. Why would God put himself in such a situation to be cursed by someone? Why would he need others curse or boon to decide his avatars or anything for that matter?

Comment: @PrashanthBl He needs some reason to play his sports (leela), though sometimes exact reason would be difficult to find.

Comment: @PrashanthBl: Thanks.! Well, my answer to your next question is again God's will. Ultimately, He is the director of all the events. How would be the effect of curses and boons or anything is as per His wish.

Comment: Well, It's just that it sounds very odd to hear something like 'cursing God!'

Comment: You can show other reference form valmiki ramayana and vyasa puranas