# Why is Lingam said to be the symbol of phallus(Penis)resting in the middle of a rimmed, disc-shaped yoni(Vagina)?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

I have come across the following information online on lingam:

The **lingam is often represented alongside the yoni** (Sanskrit word, literally "origin" or "source" or "womb"), a symbol of the goddess or of Shakti, female creative energy.The union of lingam and yoni represents the "indivisible two-in-oneness of male and female, the passive space and active time from which all life originates".

Please shed some light on this with references.

Comment: See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14214/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks I will go though it.