# Is there any erroneous belief to worship of Shiva Linga?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

As we know that penis is the most hidden part of body, and society could not accept to see any one nude. Then isn't it disrespecting to worship Lord Shiva's penis ?

Comment: Shiva-Linga is a symbol of that which is invisible yet omnipresent. It is hence a a visible symbol of the Ultimate Reality which is present in us. It is non anthropomorphic. i.e.Amanaviya ( non Human , non bodily)

Comment: Linga is Aruparupa (form without form). It is not Phallus. Linga is **mark** of Lord. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14214/3500).